# How to use resetMocks:true with module factory mocks

Tags: jestjs

I would like to mock imported modules while keeping my unit tests independent of each other.

Setting resetMocks:true in my Jest config file means that behaviour set up using [module factory mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) is lost ([issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7573)). Setting up module mocks in any other way doesn't work ([issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582)).

Changing to resetMocks:false couples the unit tests and makes the order they are executed matter, which goes against unit testing best practices.

I have tried calling `jest.mock('./a', () => {/* implementation */})` inside `beforeEach()` and at the top of `test()`. I have also tried to use a reference to a `jest.fn()` inside the module factory mock and then call `.mockImplementation()` on that reference.

Minimum demonstration:

```js
// greeter.ts
export class Greeter {
    sayHello(): string {
        return 'hello world!';
    }
}
```

```js
// module-mocking.spec.ts
import { Greeter } from "./greeter";

jest.mock('./greeter', () => ({
    Greeter: jest.fn(() => ({ sayHello: () => 'goodbye world!' }))
}));

test('mocked module behaviour should exist', () => {
    const result = new Greeter().sayHello();

    expect(result).toEqual('goodbye world!');
});
```

This test fails with the error:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).sayHello is not a function

Moving the `jest.mock()` inside `beforeEach()` or into `test()` results in:

> Expected: "goodbye world!" Received: "hello world!"

## Edit

I managed to work around this by using `require` instead of `import`. The question still remains for ES6 imports.

```js
// module-mocking.spec.ts
const greeter = require("./greeter");

let mockGreeter: any;

beforeEach(() => {
    mockGreeter = { sayHello: () => 'goodbye world!' };
    greeter.Greeter = jest.fn(() => mockGreeter);
});

test('mocked module behaviour should exist', () => {
    const result = new Greeter().sayHello();

    expect(result).toEqual('goodbye world!');
});
```